# Open Crystal Report in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I've created a crystal report then after creating it, I've created a winform where I've import crystal report library (shown in code) and used a report viewer to view the report but i not able to view the report, the code, i am new with Crytal Reports, the code I've done is :

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

namespace InventorySoftware
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();



        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string ReportSources = "";
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load("C:\\Users\\Ahsan\\Desktop\\PROJECT INVENTORY SOFTWARE\\InventorySoftware\\InventorySoftware\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
            reportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            reportViewer1.Refresh();

        }
    }
}
```

it's giving error at    `reportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;`  and the error is

```
Error   1   'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'ReportSource' and no extension method 'ReportSource' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\PROJECT INVENTORY SOFTWARE\InventorySoftware\InventorySoftware\Form1.cs  34  27  InventorySoftware
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong classes/controls for Crystal Reports.

Place a `CrystalReportViewer` control on your form. Although with later versions of Visual Studio you have to [download it separately](http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/index.html), it was still [shipped with VS2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317789/en-us).

If you don't see it in your toolbox, right-click anywhere in your toolbox and click "Choose Items...".

[image]

After checking it and pressing OK, it should be added to your toolbox. Remove your existing report control and drop a crystal report viewer on the form:

[image]

The necessary crystal references will be added to your project when you drop the viewer on it.

Add this `using` directive to the top of your code-behind:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
```

Then load your report into the viewer:

```
var cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt.Load(@"C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\PROJECT INVENTORY SOFTWARE\InventorySoftware\InventorySoftware\CrystalReport1.rpt");
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

**EDIT:**

Change the targeted framework from *.NET Framework 4 Client Profile* to *.NET Framework 4*:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply but there is no tool in my VS2008 with name CrystalReportViewer but the ReportViewer alone is

Comment: there are alot of crystal report reference which one should i add?

Comment: i've added all the reference with crystal report but still the same error :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50916/discussion-between-jack-frost-and-grant-winney)

Comment: the error is " Error 1 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'ReportSource' and no extension method 'ReportSource' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\PROJECT INVENTORY SOFTWARE\InventorySoftware\InventorySoftware\Form1.cs 42 27 InventorySoftware
"

Comment: not working out for me :(, i though you will not believe me thats why i created a video for you , the link of video is :  http://screencast.com/t/Ed4XGzFAn

Comment: it's still not comming ::(

Comment: i've installed VS2010 but stil same problem is arising , my rest of software is working absolutely fine in VS2010 but i'm not able to see CrystalReportViewer there too :/

Comment: can you please come on team sometime and can check what's the problem here , please if you can

Comment: give your ans a vote because at least you tried to help me out at your best mate, thanks for your feedback. :)

Comment: yup bro it was on Client Profile and finally i figured it out :) m happy :)