# Deploy an application with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I develop a Visual Basic application under Visual Studio and I use Crystal Report to generate the reports. Now I have to distribute the application with other users but without installing Visual Studio or Crystal Report.

I searched on the internet, I found tracks but I can not solve the problem (I do not find the crystal files reports in the Merge Modules folder) or I do not do things correctly.

I use: Visual studio 2010, Crystal Report 2010 (64 bits)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Its rather old but can help: [Open Crystal Report in Winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142526/open-crystal-report-in-winform)

Answer (score 0):

In case of web app you nedd to install crystal report redistributable on web server. 
In windows app you need add crystal reports in the prerequisites section

Comment: where i can find the prerequisites section  ? i don't undestand

Comment: in setup project go to properties and then Prerequisites.

Comment: https://mspeduardoramirez.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/13.png tha pic i found is in spanish but its ok

Comment: Hi Cflores, i can't result the problem with this solution

Comment: your installer is click once o setup project ?

Comment: try to download the crystal reports runtime and install in the client.

Comment: but must install visual studio before crystal reports ? my installer is click once

Comment: here is the runtime https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads try to install y then try to find the crystal report complement to add to your set up